# Break a javascript code into two function and link the function to html

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to change the look of the base map when I click on the list. I have a working javascript code. I tried to separate the one javascript code into two functions. so that I can pass the function to each list and change the map according to which list is clicked. But the code is not working.

Full Javascript code

```
require([
  "esri/config",
  "esri/Map",
  "esri/views/MapView",

  "esri/widgets/BasemapToggle",
  "esri/widgets/BasemapGallery"

], function(esriConfig, Map, MapView, BasemapToggle) {

  esriConfig.apiKey = "YOUR_API_KEY";

  const map = new Map({
    basemap: "arcgis-topographic"
  });

  const view = new MapView({
    container: "viewDiv",
    map: map,
    center: [-118.80543,34.02700],
    zoom: 13
  });

  const basemapToggle = new BasemapToggle({
    view: view,
    nextBasemap: "arcgis-imagery"
 });

  view.ui.add(basemapToggle,"top-right");

});
```

HTML

```
{% load static%}
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
    <title>ArcGIS API for JavaScript Tutorials: Display a map</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/4.23/esri/themes/light/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static '/css/map.css' %}">
    <script src="https://js.arcgis.com/4.23/"></script>
    
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="viewDiv" class="viewDiv"></div>
    <div class = 'img_wrap'>
        <img src="{% static '/images/rocket.jpg' %}"  class ="image1" alt="My image"> 
        <div class="vertical-menu">
            <a onclick='imagery()'href="#">Satellite</a>
            <a  onclick='streetmap()' href="#">Streetview</a>
        </div>
    </div>  
    <script src="{% static '/js/arc.js' %}"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

What I tried

```
require([
    "esri/config",
    "esri/Map",
    "esri/views/MapView",
  
    "esri/widgets/BasemapToggle",
    "esri/widgets/BasemapGallery"
  
  ], function(esriConfig, Map, MapView, BasemapToggle) {
  
    esriConfig.apiKey = "YOUR_API_KEY";
  
    const map = new Map({
      basemap: "arcgis-topographic"
    });
  
    const view = new MapView({
      container: "viewDiv",
      map: map,
      center: [-118.80543,34.02700],
      zoom: 13
    });
  });

function imagery(){

    const view = new MapView({
      container: "viewDiv",
      map: map,
      center: [-118.80543,34.02700],
      zoom: 13
    })
    const basemapToggle = new BasemapToggle({
      view: view,
      Basemap: "arcgis-imagery"
   })
    return basemapToggle
    // view.ui.add(basemapToggle,"top-right");
  
  }
  
  function streetmap(){
    const view = new MapView({
      container: "viewDiv",
      map: map,
      center: [-118.80543,34.02700],
      zoom: 13
    })
    const nav = new BasemapToggle({
      view: view,
      Basemap: "arcgis-navigation"
   })
    return nav
  }
```

Comment: It will not work because the map is set using `function(esriConfig, Map, MapView, BasemapToggle)` and not just on its own

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/74154/using-custom-basemaps-with-basemaptoggle-widget